# Функция округления в большую сторону

Tags: php

Возникла следующая проблема.
Нужна функция для округления числа до сотых в большую сторону.
Изначально функция имела следующий вид:

```
function round_up($value, $precision) {
 $pow = pow ( 10, $precision );
 return ceil($value * $pow) / $pow;
}
```

но возникла проблема при передаче в функцию следующего значения
`round_up(740*0.006,2)`
она выдает 4,45 вместо 4,44.
Далее функцию подкорректировал в следующий вид:

```
function round_up ( $value, $precision ) {
        $pow = pow ( 10, $precision ); 
        return ceil(round($value * $pow,2)) / $pow;
    }
```

предыдущую проблему решила, но возникла также новая
при передаче в функцию след.значения:

```
round_up(3208.34*0.006,2)
```

она выдает 19,25 вместо 19,26.
Может кто уже сталкивался с таким?
Заранее большое спасибо!!!

Comment: tl;dw: у числа с запятой конечная точность, в которую вы и упираетесь. Проще всего использовать функцию `number_format()`.

Comment: попробовал Ваш вариант, тоже самое:
$num = 3208.34*0.006;  
    echo number_format($num, 2, '.', '').'<br>';  
Результат 19,25

Comment: Да, без округления получаем такое значение, но я основываюсь на полученном значении с приложения Microsoft Excel, вот как раз там данная операция после прохода через функцию ceiling и дает 19,26.

Comment: Я думал-думал и ничего (хорошего) не придумал. В принципе ваша изначальная задумка верная, но ей мешает то, что результирующее число может быть чуть-чуть больше ожидаемого. Есть несколько вариантов, все плохие, но суть примерно такова: либо сравниваются строковые представления числа "до" и "после", либо от числа отнимается какая-нибудь одна стотысячная в надежде на то, что она нивелирует точность float. Когда я работал в одном проекте с мобильным оператором, там на это забили и все расчеты производили в числах, в 10000 раз больше реальных.

Comment: function round_up ($num, $precision) { 
        $pow = pow(10, $precision); 
        return ceil($num * $pow - 0.00000000001)/$pow; 
        
    }
вот такой вариант заработал и на старой версии php, может кому станет полезным. Версия php 5.2.14.
Спасибо, Etki

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
function round_up ( $value, $precision ) {
    $pow = pow ( 10, $precision ); 
    return round($value * $pow + 0.49999999999) / $pow;
}
```

Тогда, первая приведенная вами функция работает правильно, но ошибка возникает из-за погрешности вычислений.
я думаю, что `pow ( 10, 2.0 )` выдаст не ровно 100 а что-то типа 100.000001
Если необходимо округлять строго до 2 знаков попробуйте

```
function round_up($value) {
  return ceil($value * 100) / 100;
}
```

Comment: Попробуйте так: function round_up ( $value, $precision ) { $pow = pow ( 10, $precision ); return round($value * $pow + 0.49999999999) / $pow; } Пробовал, выдает нужное значение 19,26; Такое же значение выдает и первый вариант функции, который я указал в вопросе, а вот при подстановке в Ваш пример значения 740*0,006 результат 4,45, а надо 4,44.

Comment: Данный вариант пробовал ещё с самого начала.  
Наткнувшись на эту статью:  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7825321/php-ceil-gives-wrong-results-if-input-is-a-float-with-no-decimal  
подумал что функция ceil не совсем верно воспринимает тип float,
вот последнее то что пробовал:  
function round_up ($value) {  
        return ceil($value) / 100;  
    }  
    $num = (int)(3208.34*0.006*100);  
    echo round_up($num,2);  
Результат 19,25; при подстановке 740*0.006*100 выдает как и надо 4,44.  
Вообщем не могу понять, как это считается в екселе.  
=ОКРУГЛВВЕРХ(3208,34*0,006;2) выдает 19,26

Comment: function round_up ($value) { return ceil($value) / 100; } $num = (int)(3208.34*0.006*100); echo round_up($num,2);

Comment: Ошибку понял, но ошибочно переданный второй параметр не повлиял на общую картину..

Comment: `function round_up ($num, $precision)
{
  $pow = pow(10, $precision);
  return round($num * $pow + 0.49999999999)/$pow;
} ` выдает 19.26 и 4.44

Comment: function round_up ($num, $precision) { 
       $pow = pow(10, $precision); 
       return round($num * $pow + 0.49999999999)/$pow; 
  }    echo round_up(740*0.006,2); 
результат 4,45

Comment: Странно: `<?php
function round_up ($num, $precision)
{
  $pow = pow(10, $precision);
  return round($num * $pow+0.49999999999)/$pow;
}

echo '3208.34*0.006=';
echo 3208.34*0.006;
echo ' round_up=';
echo round_up(3208.34*0.006,2);
echo '<br>';
echo '740*0.006=';
echo 740*0.006;
echo ' round_up=';
echo round_up(740*0.006,2);`

выдает:
`3208.34*0.006=19.25004 round_up=19.26
740*0.006=4.44 round_up=4.44`

Comment: точно, странно.
вот моя выдача: 3208.34*0.006=19.25004 round_up=19.26
740*0.006=4.44 round_up=4.45

Comment: а какая у Вас версия php?

Comment: да, запустил Ваш код на другой версии php, все работает как у Вас, спасибо!

Comment: /var/www/html# php -v
PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.6 (cli) (built: Feb 13 2015 19:17:11)

Comment: function round_up ($num, $precision) { 
        $pow = pow(10, $precision); 
        return ceil($num * $pow - 0.00000000001)/$pow; 
        
    }
вот такой вариант заработал и на старой версии php, может кому станет полезным. Версия php 5.2.14

Answer (score 0):

Извините, Вы пытаетесь придумать новый способ округления? Почему это 3208,34*0,006 должно давать 19,26? Если результат без округления равно 19,25004. Рекомендую ознакомиться с существующими общепринятыми правилами округления, ведь вы используете в своей функции функцию ceil, которая основана на правилах округления. А если Вы пытаетесь использовать правило, которую сами придумываете, то тут уже Вам придется полностью переписать свой алгоритм округления.

Comment: она и используется в вышеприведенном примере

Comment: Я имел ввиду, что по правилам округления 19,25004 = 19,25, но никак не 19,26, т.к. при округлении до сотых (два знака после запятой), "влияние" имеет только 3-й знак, т.е. цифра 0 после 5, а все остальные числа просто отбрасываются (вообще не учитываются). Судя по всему автор пытается округлять поэтапно, что по правилам округления не допускается. Поэтому я и предложил ознакомится с правилами округления.

Comment: внесите поправку в вопрос. Округление наверх как раз предполагает 19.26

Comment: Если округлять поэтапно наверх, то 19,25004 = 19,2501 = 19,251 = 19,26, то да. Но по правилам ТАК не округляется, даже при выборе способа округления "на верх". При округлении, незначащие разряды вообще отбрасываются, т.е. 19,250 = 19,25, а 0,00004, вообще не учитывается. И правила эти применяются во всех встроенных функциях. Погуглите "Правила округления"

Comment: @VasilBaymurzin, то есть по вашей теории округление в большую сторону в Microsoft Excel, также в АКС банка, где используется функция ceiling производится не по правилам округления?? ну ну..

Comment: @VasilBaymurzin 740*0.006 = 4,44, а текущая версия на сотую лезет наверх.

Comment: Да, прошу прощения ). Но это была не моя теория, а правила округления к ближайшему целому. Признаю, попутал правила.

Comment: Спасибо за диалог, зато теперь буду знать )

Answer (score 0):

Основная беда при работе с числами с плавающей точкой в том, что их внутреннее представление может отличаться, да и почти всегда отличается от десятичного. То бишь изначально, часто они являются иррациональными числами в десятичном представлении.

Решение поставленной задачи (округление вверх, положительные числа) - грубо округлять вниз, потом сравнивать результат с исходником.
Если разница между исходником и округлением больше нуля, то прибавить к результату значимую единицу.

```
function round_up($number, $digits=2) {
    $limit = pow(0.1, $digits);  // значимая единица. по умолчанию 0.01
    $pow_limit = pow(10,$digits); // обратное значение. по умолчанию 100
    $floor_nl = floor($number*$pow_limit)/$pow_limit; // грубое округление
    $need_up = (($number - $floor_nl) > 0); // флаг, нужен ли инкремент.

    if ($need_up) { $floor_nl+= $limit; }
    return $floor_nl; 
}
```

Для учёта отрицательных чисел надо добавить соответствующую проверку.

Comment: Ваш вариант проверил, решение на самом деле очень хорошее!!
Спасибо!!
Отрицательные числа в моем случае не нужны, так как это расчет комиссии по платежам..

Comment: Проверил работу на некоторых суммах операций, в них входят и проблемные.. все отработало на отлично!